# My Array Restarts and Not Append

Tags: ios, swift

```
 class NewCourseViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var courseNameTextField: UITextField!


     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using       segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        if segue.identifier == "newClassComplete" {

if let vcSendingToo = segue.destination as?              CoursesTableViewController {

// Pass courseName to nameOfCourses Array

  // Course Name
  let courseName = courseNameTextField.text!
  vcSendingToo.nameOfCourse = courseName
  vcSendingToo.nameOfCourses.append(vcSendingToo.nameOfCourse)


}


class CoursesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var nameOfCourses = [String]()
var nameOfCourse = ""



}
```

It restarts to a blank array rather than add a value to the same array. I can't find any examples that are online that'll help resolve my issue. It was working fin then stopped all of a su

Comment: `var nameOfCourses = [String]()` => `var nameOfCourses = [String]`? I don't speak Swift, but your version doesn't create a new array? Or check if `vcSendingToo.nameOfCourses` exists and is not `nil` there, because you shouldn't be able to `append()` is that case.

Comment: You can't expect anyone to just read your code and figure out how to help you. Please describe first what you are trying to achieve. The code you post should be your attempt to solve the problem you describe.

Comment: in swift you create a new array with `[String]()`

Comment: Your segue is pushing on a new instance of your `CoursesTableViewController`.  You probably want to use a delegate to tell the original `CoursesTableViewController` to add a new course to its array and then pop/dismiss your `NewCourseViewController`.

Comment: i think the problem is that you always create a new `CoursesTableViewController` and thats why the array is always new and empty. attach your `nameOfCourses` to a other class with is more stable and more availabel (controller / repository) etc

Comment: how do you keep you array's content alive? there is no indication in your code you'd do anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change this line

```
let courseName = courseNameTextField.text!
vcSendingToo.nameOfCourse = courseName
vcSendingToo.nameOfCourses.append(vcSendingToo.nameOfCourse)
```

to this?

```
let courseName = courseNameTextField.text ?? "" //validate for nil
vcSendingToo.nameOfCourse = courseName
vcSendingToo.nameOfCourses = [courseName]
```

Answer (score -3):

I made the variables global and removed the "vcSendingToo" properties.

Comment: that's VERY VERY VERY bad design. It makes things non-Object Oriented. the `nameOfCourses` is a property of `CoursesTableViewController` and it should be dealt in the same way.